# Show that T is projection Map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $T : \mathbb{R}^n → \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear map that satisfies $T(T(x)) = T(x)$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Prove that $T$ is the projection onto $Im (T)$ with respect to $\ker(T)$.

I already proved that $\ker(T)$ and $Im(T)$ are complements in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please include your thoughts on the problem so we can help you in the best way possible!

Comment: What is your definition of a projection onto one subspace with respect to another subspace?

Comment: T(v + w) = v implies T is a projection map

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already proved that $\ker T$ and $\operatorname{Im}T$ are complementary, all that remains to be proved is that $\mathbb{R}^n=\ker T+\operatorname{Im}T$. But that is easy. Take $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $v=T(v)+\bigl(v-T(v)\bigr)$, $T(b)\in\operatorname{Im}$ and, since$$T\bigl(v-T(v)\bigr)=T(v)-T\bigl(T(v)\bigr)=T(v)-T(v)=0,$$ $v-T(v)\in\ker T$.

Comment: I already have proved that they are complements. I want to prove that T(v + w) = T(v) where v belongs to S_1 and w belongs S_2